# Using base64 string with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, base64, nsurlconnection

I am using a NSURLConnect call and I get unsupported URL when I have a space in my query string. To fix this I converted the string to base64 and I am still getting errors. How do I send a base64 string though NSUrlConnect successfully? If this isn't possible, how do I safely send a string with a space in it?

```
NSData *convertData = [queryWS dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
queryWS = [convertData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest =
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:queryWS]];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
if (!error) {
  responseDictionary =
  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:0
                                    error:&parseError];
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to convert the URL string to base64 encoding. What you want is to properly escape any special characters in the URL. Please see the `NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method or `NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` if you only need to support iOS 9 or later.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *queryString = @"SOME_QUERY_STRING";
NSString *encodedQueryString = [queryString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```